# For loop multiplication table

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Excuse me as I am a beginner. I am wondering why int i does not increase when the output is printed and instead just keeps printing "2 x 1 = 2" 
I am trying to print the output of a multiplication table of 2 by 1-10

```
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 2;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      System.out.println(N + " " + "x" + " " + i + " " + "=" + " " + (i * N));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code works properly: http://ideone.com/Reqc5r

Comment: Your code prints all values

Comment: Indeed, are you sure you recompiled and such?

Comment: It's generally better and more readable to combine neighboring `String` literals, so `" " + "x" + " "` can be changed to `" x "`.

Answer (score -1):

Okay it does work. For some reason it wasn't working in Eclipse but it does in BlueJ. Thankyou.